# схлопывается форма

Tags: html, css

```
&__form{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 545px;
    height: 57px !important;
    border:1px solid white;
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 57px;
}
```

Не пойму что не так: когда меняешь ширину окна на меньший на определенном моменте и когда переходишь на версию сайта для планшетов и мобилок высота формы равна 0.

Comment: Посмотрите на @media запросы, если используете css фреймворк проверьте на наличие стилей в html для самой формы и ее контейнера (подобных hidden-xs)

Comment: код бы увидеть весь, причины могут быть разные